# random images from existing database

Tags: php, mysql

i have 4 different database video,wallpapers, pictures, games and i want to display random items on external page i.e home page different video wallpaper pictures and games whenever page is refresh i want to fetch thumbnail and content randomly   with the help of php

for example :-i have games database where thumbnail and swf files stored and these files randomly fetch on my home page and when user click on that file it send user to that game page

is it ok to fetch content with id? i think it will create problem for 150x150px div where i want thumbnail to be displayed.

here is example of database

```
[games][1]
[pictures][2]
[wallpapers][4]
please help me guys 


  [1]: http://pzy.be/v/3/game.jpg
  [2]: http://pzy.be/v/2/pictures.jpg
  [3]: http://pzy.be/v/2/video.jpg
  [4]: http://pzy.be/v/4/wall.jpg
```

Comment: not getting ur question correctly .

Comment: sorry if u dont get it  actually i want to show random thumbnail from different database(as i mentioned above) on different div on my home page

Comment: build an array with all of your image and use the array_rand() function to select random id, ex  $id =array_rand($ar); echo $ar[$id]; aafter, del element unset($ar[$id]); and go on

Answer (score 3):

for fetching random data from database you have to write your query like this example

```
select column_name from table_name where condition RAND()
```

and your data will be random whenever this query executes.

Comment: Ok, RAND() is random, but are we sure that expanded value from function is correct id for condiction? May will be null result.

Comment: can you please give me example i m bit confuse

Comment: rand function it slow for large database

Comment: yes `RAND` is slow for large database. But you can optimize your query by creating indexes in database.